# Is this a correct way to stop a thread if it hasn't finished after a set period of time?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class TimeToDieThread extends Thread implements Runnable
{
    private Runnable r;
    private long lTimeLength;//time NanoTime

    public TimeToDieThread(Runnable r, long lTimeLength)
    {
        super();
        this.r = r;
        this.lTimeLength = lTimeLength;
    }
    public void start() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean bran = false;
                while ((!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) && (bran == false)) {
                    r.run();
                    bran = true;
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        // Sleep a for entire length, and then interrupt
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(lTimeLength);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Interrupted, wop wop waa");
        }
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: `r.run()` will not get interrupted in this way, no. `t.run()` could get interrupted before running the while loop (which only loops once anyways, typo?).

Answer (score 2):

It is rarely necessary to use `Thread` directly (and it's definitely not necessary to extend `Thread` and implement `Runnable`, because `Thread` already implements `Runnable`).

Use an `ExecutorService`, submit a `Runnable` to that, and use the `get(long, TimeUnit)` method on the returned `Future` to wait for it to complete.

```
// Construct this somewhere. Note that you also need to shut it down somewhere.
// This is just an example of how you might construct it; other executors are
// available.
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

Future<?> future = executorService.submit(yourRunnable);
future.get(timeout, timeoutUnit);  // Exception handling omitted.
// Cancel if it is still running.
future.cancel(true);
```